# java.lang.Exception: No Certificate file specified or invalid file format

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, deployment, jboss

I am getting below error while deploying through jboss 5.1.1:

```
2014-03-18 08:44:57,834 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] Error initializing endpoint
java.lang.Exception: No Certificate file specified or invalid file format
        at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSLContext.setCertificate(Native Method)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.init(AprEndpoint.java:660)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol.init(Http11AprProtocol.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1029)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:821)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatService.startService(TomcatService.java:313)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:376)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.pojoStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:216)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
        at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
        at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:243)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:111)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:72)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:221)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
        at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
```

Comment: And your SSL configuration for this connector is ... ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had fixed this issue, like doing this:

1. Go to Tomcat installation directory
2. Find the server.xml
3. Change the protocol from `"HTTP/1.1"` to `"org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"` in the `<Connector>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs across this thread in the future, for JBoss 5.1.2 I had to set the protocol to org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol, org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Find the `server.xml`(under this folder structure - jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\ ..app folder name.. \deploy\jboss-web.deployer) then change the protocol from `HTTP/1.1` to `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol` in the tag.

Tested for `JBoss 4.2.3.GA`